# Cordova plugins don't work after running cordova build android or build release

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic4

I'm running into problems when I try to build my ionic app for the android platform. Running cordova build android appears to be successful, but the cordova plugins are no longer working on my android device. My app is working very well when I use chrome or devapp tool....With devapp tool all the cordova plugins work very well, but when I run cordova build android release version the cordova plugins stop working....

I am using ionic 4 with cordova 9.0.0 and I'm working in linux.

When i connect my device in chrome remote device I obtain this error for the cordova camera plugin, "plugin camera not installed" but this plugin is installed..  my external link not working too(window.open)...Scan code with bar code scanner plugin not working, etc.

Comment: Exactly what plugin function is not working? Surely the plugin is not correctly installed, or you are invoking it improperly.